# Hive for flutter just returns the Instance instead of the actual value

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, hive, nosql

I have decided to go with [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) as my settings/preference storage. However, I am not able to implement my `Storage` class correctly because the `getValue` method always returns `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'` instead of the actual value. Does anyone know how to fix that?

My `Storage` class just contains the `getValue` and `setValue` which always opens the hive box and then either should set or get the value. Also, I have created the enum `StorageKeys` in order to have a set of keys and make sure I get or set the value to the deticated key.

main.dart

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    routes: {
      "/": (context) => const Home(),
    },
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  get() async {
    return await Storage.getValue(StorageKeys.authTokenKey);
  }

  void set() async {
    await Storage.setValue(StorageKeys.authTokenKey, 'TestValue');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    set();
    print(get());

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: ChevronNavigation(),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

storage.dart

```
class Storage {
  static const preferencesBox = '_storageBox';

  static Future<void> setValue(StorageKeys key, dynamic value) async {
    final storage = await Hive.openBox<dynamic>(preferencesBox);
    storage.put(key.toString(), value);
  }

  static dynamic getValue(StorageKeys key) async {
    final storage = await Hive.openBox<dynamic>(preferencesBox);
    return await storage.get(key.toString(), defaultValue: null) as dynamic;
  }
}

enum StorageKeys {
  authTokenKey,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(get());` will give you `Instance of Future<dynamic>` since `get()` returns a Future object.

### SOLUTION:

You need to await the actual value in the Future object by writing `await` before `get()` in a Future method.

Like this:

```
print(await get());
```

In your question above, this cannot work as the build method cannot be async. You can put the `print(await get())` in a separate method and have it in your `initState`.

Like this:

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    callGet();
  }

  Future<void> callGet() async {
    print(await get());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the `await Storage.getValue(StorageKeys.authTokenKey);` value, and as it is a Future, you get this message.

You should try to call it on your initState and then get the Hive value. When the value returns you cant print it.

Eg:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Storage.getValue(StorageKeys.authTokenKey).then((value) => print(value));
  }
```